# General affine group of degree one on field of order 4

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, linear-groups

I want to show $AGL(1,4)$ is isomorphic to $A_4$.
I know that $AGL1(k)≅k⋊k^×$, where the semi-direct product is given by the natural action of $k^×$ on $k$ by multiplication.
But I dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the other answers. You may also remark that $AGL(1,4)$ acts faithfully on $\mathbb{F}_4$ which is a set of cardinal $4$. In particular, the structural morphism of this action allows you to identify $AGL(1,4)$  to a subgroup of $S_4$.

Now $AGL(1,4)$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $S_4$ and thus $AGL(1,4)=A_4$.

Answer (score 1):

The group $AGL(1,q)\cong \Bbb{F}_q\rtimes \Bbb{F}_q^{\times}$ hays order $q(q-1)$, and its derived groups is isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}_q$ for $q>2$. For $q=4$ this means,
$G=AGL(1,4)$ has order $12$ with derived subgroup of order $4$. So $G$ is metabelian, but not abelian and not nilpotent. Furthermore it is not supersolvable, since $4$ is not prime. I suppose, together with the classification list of groups of order $12$ we can now see that $G\cong A_4$:

[Classification of groups of order 12](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546577/classification-of-groups-of-order-12)

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $k$ the field with $4$ elements. The group of transformations $x\mapsto ax+ b$ imbeds into the group of permutations of $k$. Each translation by an element $b\ne 0$ of $k$ is product of two disjoint transpositions if $a\ne 0$ since $b+b=0$ so $x\mapsto x+b \mapsto x$. Each multiplication by an element $a\ne 1$ is a cycle of length $3$ since $a^3=1$ so 
$x\mapsto a x \mapsto a^2 x \mapsto x$ ($0$ is fixed). So all the transformation
$x\mapsto ax+b$ are even permutation of $k$. Looking at the orders, we conclude that they give all the even permutations of $k$.